# How to integrate search by tag functionality into the wordpress with eloquent?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, eloquent

I have integrated wp-eloquent with wordpress and I would like to create a relation between tags and posts.

Normally wordpress built-in functions are using this type of queries which is pretty good:

```
SELECT *
FROM 0UU60c51_term_relationships
JOIN 0UU60c51_term_taxonomy
ON 0UU60c51_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 0UU60c51_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN 0UU60c51_terms
ON 0UU60c51_terms.term_id = 0UU60c51_term_taxonomy.term_id
WHERE object_id = '13944' AND taxonomy = 'post_tag';
```

I am using this relations and this methods:

namespace WeDevs\ORM\WP;
use WeDevs\ORM\Eloquent\Model;

```
/**
 * Class Post
 *
 * @package WeDevs\ORM\WP
 */
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags(){
        return $this->terms("post_tag");
    }

    public function terms($term_type)
    {
        $closure = (function($query) use ($term_type) {
            $query = $query->where("taxonomy",$term_type);
            return $query;
        }); 
        return $this->belongsToMany('WeDevs\ORM\WP\Term','0UU60c51_term_relationships','object_id','term_taxonomy_id')->whereHas("term_taxonomy", $closure);
    }
```

Actually results are the same for both :

```
print_pre(Post::find(13944)->tags->lists("name"));
```

But unless I didn't use lists method it brings a lot of queries, objects and results with the eloquent object. Is there a way to not getting relations and only getting tags without anything else ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fetch? The tags of a post or a post with a tag? For the first one: `Post::find(13944)->tags->get()` - *will return a collection of the tags, for the second one: `$post = Post::find(13944)` and accessing the tags and other data: `$post->tags`.

Comment: I want to get tags in a array without getting relations.

Comment: What do you mean by `relations`? This: `Post::find(13944)->tags->get()->toArray()` will give you all `tags` in array.